# Proving Convergence of Sinusoidal Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am asked to consider the limit of the following sequence:

$$ s_n=\frac{1}{n}\sin n$$

Splitting the sequence up, I know that as $n\to\infty$, $\frac{1}{n}\to0$. Similarly, as $n\to\infty$, $\sin n\in[-1,1]$ as it is oscillating. The product of $0$ and any number in the latter interval is $0$, thus:

$$\lim s_n=0$$

However, I have just begun real analysis and have been asked to prove this using the definition of convergence of some sequence $s_n$ using the following definition:

$$\exists\; s\in\Bbb R,\forall\; \epsilon>0,\exists\;N\in\Bbb N:n\geq N\Rightarrow|s_n-s|<\epsilon$$

Normally I would attempt to work backwards from here to isolate $n$ in terms of $\epsilon$.

$$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sin n-0 \right|<\epsilon$$

However, I can't do this given the nature of the sequence. Thus, I'm going to arbitrarily assign $\epsilon=\frac{1}{10}$

Accounting for the range of sine, I know the following:

$$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sin n\right|\leq\left|\frac{1}{n}\right|$$

Thus, let $N=11$. In that case, $\forall\;n\geq N$:

$$\epsilon=\frac{1}{10}>\left|\frac{1}{n}\right|\geq\left|\frac{1}{n}\sin n\right|$$

This completes the proof.

Is this a valid approach to the problem and was there an easier way to solve it?

Comment: Wait, why did you arbitrarily assign $\epsilon = \dfrac{1}{10}$? $N=11$ only works for  $\epsilon\ge\dfrac{1}{10}$. What about lesser epsilons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution only accounts for $\epsilon\ge\dfrac{1}{10}$. Proving that the sequence is convergent to $0$ will involve finding $N$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

With this problem aside, you noted that 
$$\left|\dfrac{1}{n}\sin n\right|\le\left|\dfrac{1}{n}\right|$$
So, given any $\epsilon>0$, we can choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}<N$$
So, for any $n\ge N$, we have
$$\dfrac{1}{n}=\left|\dfrac{1}{n}\right|<\epsilon$$
And you can apply the same $N$ to your sinusoidal sequence. This proves the convergence to $0$.